# Recursively rename files based on the upper folder names

Tags: bash, find

There is a folder structure like this

```
./A/B/C/D/file.txt
```

and I want to start from `.` and recursively find `file.txt` and rename it to the two upper level folder names. So the example above should be `./A/B/C/D/C.D.txt`.

I can use `find` to recursively rename the files, but I don't know how combine that with `basename` and `dirname` to extract `C` and `D` upon a match. How can I do that?

Comment: what happens to `./A/file.txt` ?

Comment: Assume `file.txt` exists in the last level. So that is `/A/B/C/D/file.txt` to `/A/B/C/D/C.D.txt` and `/A/B/C/E/file.txt` to `/A/B/C/E/C.E.txt`. I just wrote A and B to show that upper levels are the same.

Comment: I have come up with pretty ugly solution)

`a=./A/B/C/D/file.txt;
while [[ $(echo  $a | awk -F "/" '{print NF-1}') -gt 2 ]]; do a=$(echo $a | sed -E 's/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]\///'); done && echo $a | sed 's/\//./g'`
First, we take `/` as separator and count number of fields with awk. That number - 1 is number of separators e.g. `/`.
Then we check if we have more than 2 separators and while this is true we strip folder by folder from the beginning. 
When only 2 separators left - just use sed to change `/` to `.`
I did not take into consideration filenames with spaces and other exotics.

Comment: I meant what happens if there are not two levels to build the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bash arrays:

```
find . -name 'file.txt' -exec bash -c '
    IFS=/
    for p; do
        a=($p)
        n=${#a[@]}
        ((n>3)) && echo mv "$p" "${a[*]:0:n-1}/${a[n-3]}.${a[n-2]}.txt"
    done
' -- {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something like this:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for src in ./**/*/*/file.txt; do
    dir=${src%/*} dst=${dir#"${dir%/*/*}/"} dst=$dir/${dst//\//.}.txt
    echo mv "$src" "$dst"
done
```

Remove `echo` if the output looks good.

Comment: Or `printf %s\\n ./*/*/*/*/* | sed 's@\(.*/\)\([^/]\+\)/\([^/]\+\)/.*\.txt@mv & \1\2/\3/\2.\3.txt@'`